# Flask dont add the value from requests into output.html

Tags: python, html, flask, output

#### I give up after hours of testing and testing cant get it work.

#### I have a flask script that recive requests and save them into Pet etc...

## here the code:**your text**

> from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
>
> app = Flask(**name**)
>
> @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
> def handle_request():
> data = request.get_json()
> Accessing specific values
> username = data['Username']
> pet = data['Pet']
> diamond = data['Diamond']
> earned = data['Earned']
> diamond_reopen = data['DiamondReopen']
> time = data['Time']
>
> Process the values here
> Display the data in the console
> print("Username:", username)
> print("Pet:", pet)
> print("Diamond:", diamond)
> print("Earned:", earned)
> print("DiamondReopen:", diamond_reopen)
> print("Time:", time)
>
> return redirect(url_for('output', username=username, pet=pet, diamond=diamond, earned=earned, diamond_reopen=diamond_reopen, time=time))
>
> @app.route('/output', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
> def output():
> username = request.args.get('username')
> pet = request.args.get('pet')
> diamond = request.args.get('diamond')
> earned = request.args.get('earned')
> diamond_reopen = request.args.get('diamond_reopen')
> time = request.args.get('time')
>
> return render_template('output.html', username=username, pet=pet, diamond=diamond, earned=earned, diamond_reopen=diamond_reopen, time=time)
>
> if **name** == '**main**':
> app.run(port=1756)
> **#

#### it prints the correct values in the console (the right values) but on output.html it stays **

> Username: None
>
> Pet: None
>
> Diamond: None
>
> Earned: None
>
> Diamond Reopen: None
>
> Time: None

#### Flask , jinja2 and HOURS with AI Bot but cant get the value on the html

Comment: Can you fix format and indentation? It looks messing.

Comment: Use code blocks for code (the `{}` button, or three backticks on a line by themselves to mark start and end), not block quote. Less headings please, it feels like shouting.

Answer (score 0):

did you include jinja2 correctly in your html.
Example:

```
@app.route('/show')
def simple_show_data():
    data = "From Python"
    return render_template("sample.html", data=data)
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Flaks show var data</h1>
<p>{{ data }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Visit URL:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/show

```
Flaks show var data
From Python
```